# Laptop too slow even to boot

Tags: windows-7, virus, bootrepair, hp-laptop

I have tried startup repair, taking too long(2 hrs and counting). Even safe mode isn't working(keeps showing 'loading files'). Is it because of some virus? What do you recommend i should do next?

Comment: Try downloading and booting from a live CD or USB. Could possibly be a dying hard drive.

Comment: Maybe a faulty driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of possible reasons, but by far the most common one is a dying hard drive. Depending on your data I would turn off the PC and take it to a specialist (if your data is valuable and not backed up) or, using another PC, download a USB Linux rescue disk, then boot off that and check for hard drive errors - starting by looking at S.M.AR.T errors.

If the HD is faulty, replace it and try recover your data (or restore from backup). If the HD is OK, do a filesystem check on all partitions.

If there are still problems, only then suspect a virus or other hardware issue.